# Apply tool tip to a field in mvc3 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, tooltip

I am having a field "name" in my model as follows

```
    [StringLength(50,MinimumLength=2)]
    public string name{ get; set; }
```

And in view its like as follows

```
                <li>
                 <label >
                NAME</label>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.name)
                </li>
```

Can anybody please help me to put a lengthy tool tip for this field. Its in mvc

Answer (score 0):

You can add a title attribute to the li tag and it will appear when the user hovers over it.

```
<li title="tool tip">Stuff</li>
```